# React/Redux Wrong This Context

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Okay, so this is pretty embarassing since I am pretty experienced with React, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around why `this.props` is not recognized in my `handlePress` component method.

I am unsure as to why I am able to access `this.props` inside of the following methods:

- renderError()
- renderButton()

But when I attempt to call this.props inside of `handlePress` React says it is undefined. In the code below, you can see that I attach an onPress handler to the Button, which calls `handlePress`. The `handlePress` method is called correctly, but the app crashed when I try to access props inside of it.

This does not work unless I do, `this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this)` inside of the constructor. I am confused as to why I can access the correct this context inside of the other methods when I do not bind them in the constructor.

Any help?

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  renderButton() {
    if(this.props.loading) {
      return <Spinner size="large" />
    }

    return (
      <Button onPress={this.handlePress}>
        Login
      </Button>
    )
  }

  renderError() {
    if(this.props.error) {
      return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'red', alignSelf: 'center' }}> 
            { this.props.error } 
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  handlePress() {
    const { email, password } = this.props
    this.props.loginUser({ email, password })
  }

  render() {
    const { email, updateInputField, password } = this.props

    return (
      <View>
        <Card>

          {/*
            E-Mail
          */}
          <CardSection>
            <Input
              value={email}
              onChangeText={value => updateInputField('email', value)}
              label="Email"
              autoCorrect={false}
              placeholder="example@gmail.com"
            />
          </CardSection>

          {/*
            Password
          */}
          <CardSection>
            <Input
              value={password}
              onChangeText={value => updateInputField('password', value)}
              label="Password"
              autoCorrect={false}
              secureTextEntry
            />
          </CardSection>

          { this.renderError() }

          <CardSection>
            { this.renderButton() }
          </CardSection>

        </Card>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  const { email, password, loading, error } = auth
  return { email, password, loading, error }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    updateInputField,
    loginUser
  }
  )(LoginForm)
```

Comment: when you use arrow functions instead of class methods  works as well?

Comment: This pretty much explains about why one should `bind` methods or use `arrowFunctions`. -> https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: They will work, but I am avoiding using arrow functions as class properties now, as I had a discussion with an AirBnb employee who strongly suggested against it, as it makes testing your components more difficult. I initially did not agree with him, but I would rather do things the right way, versus having some syntactic sugar that ends up making testing more hacky.

Comment: I am also very curious at what moment you lose the binding. I usually do arrow functions in case of now, but I would definitely gain at having a better understanding of it!

Comment: In short: event handlers are called externally vs methods called within the same class/object scope.

Comment: So that Button component is a custom component I created which takes an onPress prop. So that function ends up being passed down into a child React Component where it is executed. I am assuming that since I am inside another function, which is another execution context, the this variable is bound to that child components execution context. I was able to prove this by console.logging the this context when the button is clicked, and sure enough, it was referring to the Button component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
<Button onPress={this.handlePress}>
    Login
</Button>
```

You are not invoking the `handlePress` function within the context of the current component, instead you are assigning a reference of it to the onPress prop being passed on to the Button.

Now when the button triggers the handlePress method,  is when it gets the context. It won't refer to the context you want it to run in, unless you bind the handlePress method in constructor or use arrow function like

```
<Button onPress={(e) => this.handlePress(e)}>
    Login
</Button>
```

or

```
handlePress = (e) => {}
```